# I want to fetch current user data from firebase database in my flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, firebase-authentication

**My Question is that i want to fetch data of the current user only. but this code below is fetching data of all the users present in my Database. how can i fetch the data of only and only current user.**

1. This is the code with which i am fetching data from firebase(I am using Realtime DataBase).
   in this 'node-name' is the field under which my data is being stored.

```
class ShowDataPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowDataPageState createState() => _ShowDataPageState();
}

class _ShowDataPageState extends State<ShowDataPage> {
  List<myData> allData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    ref.child('node-name').once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      var keys = snap.value.keys;
      var data = snap.value;
      allData.clear();
      for (var key in keys) {
        myData d = new myData(
          data[key]['name'],
          data[key]['message'],
          data[key]['profession'],
        );
        allData.add(d);
      }
      setState(() {
        print('Length : ${allData.length}');
      });
    });
  }
```

2. This is the code from which i am uploading my data to the firebase under the name of 'node-name'. this code is stored in another file and is having another necessary fields also but this is the field which uploads my data to the firebase.

```
_sendToServer() {
    if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
      _key.currentState.save();
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      var data = {
        "name": name,
        "profession": profession,
        "message": message,
      };
      ref.child('node-name').push().set(data).then((v) {
        _key.currentState.reset();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autovalidate = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

3. My data base in firebase looks like given below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the user uid:

```
ref.child('node-name').child("M5CCSXQo3Upq5OC7y3lw").once()
.then((DataSnapshot snap) {...}
```

If you don't know the uid and didn't use it, then perform a query by the name fore example.

```
@override
void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
      fetchUser(user);
    });
}

fetchUser(FirebaseUser user)
{
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  ref.child('node-name').child(user.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      var keys = snap.value.keys;
      var data = snap.value;
      allData.clear();
      for (var key in keys) {
        myData d = new myData(
          data[key]['name'],
          data[key]['message'],
          data[key]['profession'],
        );
        allData.add(d);
      }
      setState(() {
        print('Length : ${allData.length}');
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: the argument type 'future string ' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'string'. this error is coming when i am trying to put current user uid in this. actually i am getting uid also from firebase using the function getUserID().

Comment: Just use: await as a prefix to .currentUser() call. or use: .currentUser().then((user){ this.user = user });

Comment: i added await an async but since this all was inside initState i was not able to do that. so i put all this current code in  widget with async function and added await and called it from initstate. but i does not seem to return anything. a blank page is being returned. what could be the possible reason for this

Comment: Just use the .then version inside the initState, and inside .then call a function that has the FirebaseDatabase call inside it.

Comment: I updated the answer, it should be something similar to that. You should be able to see now how it works. There are many other ways to approach this. It's hard to explain them here.

Comment: yeah i got it now. thank you so much for ur help. the updated answer really helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211979/discussion-between-satyam-goyal-and-aldobaie).

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
...
ref.child('node-name').child('/** current_user_key **/').once()
...
```